# Understanding the 3rd step of Nielsen and Chuang's description of the quantum order-finding algorithm

Tags: quantum-algorithms, textbook-and-exercises, nielsen-and-chuang, order-finding

In Nielsen and Chuang's description of Quantum order-finding algorithm, the 3rd step of the procedure says
$$\frac1{\sqrt{2^t}}\sum_{j=0}^{2^t-1}|j\rangle|x^j\mod N\rangle \approx \frac1{\sqrt{r2^t}}\sum_{s=0}^{r-1}\sum_{j=0}^{2^t-1}e^{2\pi isj/r}|j\rangle|u_s\rangle.$$

Why isn't this an equation but an approximation?  In fact, the Exercise 5.13 of Nielsen and Chuang proved
$$\frac1{\sqrt r}\sum_{s=0}^{r-1} e^{2\pi isk/r}|u_s\rangle = |x^k \mod N\rangle.$$
Did I miss something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approximation is addressed in the text after the period-finding algorithm, where it says that the problem is that $2^t$ may not be an integer multiple of the period $r$. As addressed in [this related answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/14889/15820), there is no approximation in step 3 *per se*, but there is definitely an approximation between steps 3 and 4 in that the inverse Fourier transform won't behave perfectly without $2^t$ being a multipole of $r$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the approximation in step 4.  I missed that.